# How to submit a chatmsg without "?save=msg" in PHP

Tags: php, chat

I'm working on a PHP chat but unfortunately I came across a problem.
It's about sending a message via "`?save=msg`".

```
"chat.php?save=msg"
```

The msg are be written in a database.

My problem is, I do not want to be able to resend the message by reloading the page.

I tried a `"Force-Reload"` for the site, but the `"?save=msg"` do not vanish through this.

`"onclick='chat.php'"` or something like this

PHP-Script

```
    if(isset($_GET['save'])) {
        $save = $_GET['save'];
        if($save == 'msg') {
            //< &lt;> &gt; & &amp;
            $uauswahl = trim($_POST['nachrichteneing']);
            if ($uauswahl != NULL){
                $uauswahl = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $uauswahl);
                $uauswahl = str_replace("<", "&lt;", $uauswahl);
                $uauswahl = str_replace(">", "&gt;", $uauswahl);
                include("str_replace.php");
                $uname = $user['benutzer'];
                $ava = $user['avatar'];
                $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO chathistory (msg, name, avatar) VALUES(:msg, :name, :avatar)");
                $result = $statement->execute(array('msg'=> $uauswahl, 'name'=> $uname, 'avatar'=> $ava));

                if ($result == true){
                    $success_msg = "Nachricht wurde gesendet.";
                } else {
                    $error_msg = "Beim Absenden der Nachricht scheint ein Fehler aufgetreten zu sein.";
                }
            } else{
                $error_msg = "Nachricht wurde nicht gesendet. </br> Grund: Nachricht darf nicht leer sein.";
            }


        }
```

My Form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="?save=msg" method="POST">
<input type="text" id="msgsf" autocomplete="off" name="nachrichteneing" placeholder="Tippe Nachricht...">
<input type="submit" id="msgfb" value="" />
</form>
```

I hope someone got a idea for this

Comment: If you want to send messages without a page refresh then you need to implement JS and use AJAX calls. If you want to implement pretty URL's then you need to use a [router](http://altorouter.com/).

Comment: You need to use AJAX to send your chat msg in order to prevent the webpage from reloading

Comment: There is really no need to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` unless you want to do a file upload.

Comment: @jaquarh @Israel Obanijesu
 i read about AJAX but i don't understand it, this don't want to go in my head.

@04FS 
`enctype="multipart/form-data"` is a leftover that i forgot.

Comment: What is that kind of `Force-Refresh` that you've tried?

Comment: @NicoHaase

`"onclick='chat.php'"`
or
`header("Location: chat.php");
die();`

Comment: And both of these calls did not kill the `GET` parameter? Sounds strange....

Comment: @Nico Haase i write the script on another part of my file and now it works with `header("Location: chat.php"); die();`

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy for the page to refresh once to submit the form then you will need to tweak your code to reference `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`. GET parameters are passed between page reloads by appending the URL where as POST are sent via headers.

From your HTML side you will need to change your action to reflect a page name and then from your code, simply swapping `$_GET` for `$_POST` should work.